KeyError: 0 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise after applying a function to a pandas dataframe
I have a rather complicated function f(featureList) that takes a list of arbitrary length as input and gives another list of the same length as output:
import math
import random
import time

def survivalNormalcdf(x):
    return (1-math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2

def normalcdf(x):
    return (1+math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2

def normalpdf(x): 
    return math.exp(-x*x/2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)

def abss(p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(abs(p[k]))
    return q;

def mult(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a*p[k])
    return q;

def add(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a[k]+p[k])
    return q

def dot(u,v,pp):
    s=0
    for k in range(len(u)):
       s+=u[k]*v[k]*pp[k]
    return s;

def grad(t,pp):
    h=math.sqrt(1/5/(len(pp)+1))
    g=[]

    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g.append(-pp[k])
        beg=t[k] - 10
        end=t[k] + 10
        qq=math.ceil((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            ss=survivalNormalcdf(x)
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                if k==m:
                    ss*=normalpdf(x-t[m])
                else:
                    ss*=survivalNormalcdf(x-t[m])
            g[k]+=ss*h;
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g[k]/=pp[k]
    return g

def iint(t,pp):
    h=0.1
    ss=0
    for k in range(1):
        beg=min(min(t),0) - 10
        end=max(max(t),0) + 10
        qq=int((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            s=1; 
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                s*=survivalNormalcdf(x-t[m])
            ss+=(s-1)*survivalNormalcdf(x)*h
        for k in range(len(pp)):
            ss-=pp[k]*t[k]
    return ss

def f(ppp):
    kk=0
    maxx=ppp[0]
    for k in range(len(ppp)):
        if ppp[k]>maxx:
            kk=k
            maxx=ppp[k]
    pp=ppp[:kk]+ppp[kk+1:]
    
    t=[]
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        t.append(math.sqrt(2*math.log(1/pp[k])))
        
    u=grad(t,pp)
    mm=0
    while mm<=50*len(pp) and sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))>1/10.0**12:
        mm+=1
        if mm%len(pp)==1:
            pass
        s=min(1,1/sum(abss(u)))
        cnt=0
        while dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(s,u)),pp),pp)>0 and s*sum(abss(u))<len(u):
            s*=2
            cnt+=1
        a=0
        b=s
        beg=a
        end=b
        A=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(a,u)),pp),pp)
        B=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(b,u)),pp),pp)
        k=0
        while k<20 and abs(A-B)>(1/10.0**12)*max(abs(A),abs(B)):
            mid=(beg+end)/2
            if dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(mid,u)),pp),pp)>0:
                beg=mid
            else:
                end=mid
            
            c=max(beg-(1/10.0**12),min(end+(1/10.0**12),b+(B/(A-B))*(b-a)))
            C=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(c,u)),pp),pp)
            if abs(a-c)>abs(b-c) and abs(b-c)>0:
                a=b
                A=B
                b=c
                B=C
            else:
                b=a
                B=A
                a=c
                A=C
            if C>0:
                beg=max(beg,c)
            else:
                end=min(end,c)
            k+=1
                
        s=c
            
        oldgrad=grad(t,pp)
        t=add(t,mult(s,u))
        newgrad=grad(t,pp)
        uold=mult(1,u)
        u=mult(1,newgrad)
        if mm%len(pp)!=1:
            u=add(u,mult(dot(newgrad, add(newgrad,mult(-1,oldgrad)),pp)/dot(oldgrad,oldgrad,pp),uold))

    
    ss=sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))
    tt=t[:kk]
    tt.append(0)
    t=tt+t[kk:]
    if ss>1/10.0**12:
        x=str(input("Failed"))
    return t

So for example, we have
f([0.2,0.1,0.55,0.15]) = [0.7980479577400461, 1.2532153405902076, 0, 0.9944188436386611]

f([0.02167131,0.17349148,0.08438952,0.04143787,0.02589056,0.03866752,0.0461553,0.09212758,0.10879326,0.186921,0.02990676,0.02731904,0.06020158,0.06302721]) = 
[1.174313198960376,
 0.04892832217716259,
 0.4858149215364752,
 0.864373517094786,
 1.0921431988531611,
 0.8989070806156786,
 0.8098127832637683,
 0.4358011113129989,
 0.3387512959281985,
 0,
 1.0239882119094197,
 1.0669265516784823,
 0.671235053100702,
 0.6466856803321204]

And I have a pandas dataframe that looks like
Class_ID  Date           Student_ID      feature  
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553                                   
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2     
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1     
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55     
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15     

and I would like to apply the function f(featureList) to the feature column groupby Class_ID and generate a new column called New_feature. And here's my code:
df['New_feature'] = df.groupby('Class_ID', group_keys=False)['feature'].apply(f)
So the desired outcome looks like:
df_outcome = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""Class_ID   Date          Student_ID      feature        New_feature
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     2.385963956274992
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     0
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     1.6510552553095719
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     2.054792417419151
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056     2.298129663961289
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     2.0916706205231286
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553       1.9965409929949391
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2            0.7980479577400461
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1            1.2532153405902076
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55           0
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15           0.9944188436386611"""))

However it gives the following error:
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 
# If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

Here is the code:
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""Class_ID  Date           Student_ID      feature  
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553                                   
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2     
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1     
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55     
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15"""))     

def survivalNormalcdf(x):
    return (1-math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2

def normalcdf(x):
    return (1+math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2

def normalpdf(x): 
    return math.exp(-x*x/2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)

def abss(p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(abs(p[k]))
    return q;

def mult(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a*p[k])
    return q;

def add(a,p):
    q=[]
    for k in range(len(p)):
        q.append(a[k]+p[k])
    return q

def dot(u,v,pp):
    s=0
    for k in range(len(u)):
       s+=u[k]*v[k]*pp[k]
    return s;

def grad(t,pp):
    h=math.sqrt(1/5/(len(pp)+1))
    g=[]

    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g.append(-pp[k])
        beg=t[k] - 10
        end=t[k] + 10
        qq=math.ceil((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            ss=survivalNormalcdf(x)
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                if k==m:
                    ss*=normalpdf(x-t[m])
                else:
                    ss*=survivalNormalcdf(x-t[m])
            g[k]+=ss*h;
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        g[k]/=pp[k]
    return g

def iint(t,pp):
    h=0.1
    ss=0
    for k in range(1):
        beg=min(min(t),0) - 10
        end=max(max(t),0) + 10
        qq=int((end-beg)/h)
        for q in range(qq):
            x=beg+q*h
            s=1; 
            for m in range(len(pp)):
                s*=survivalNormalcdf(x-t[m])
            ss+=(s-1)*survivalNormalcdf(x)*h
        for k in range(len(pp)):
            ss-=pp[k]*t[k]
    return ss

def f(ppp):
    kk=0
    maxx=ppp[0]
    for k in range(len(ppp)):
        if ppp[k]>maxx:
            kk=k
            maxx=ppp[k]
    pp=ppp[:kk]+ppp[kk+1:]
    
    t=[]
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        t.append(math.sqrt(2*math.log(1/pp[k])))
        
    u=grad(t,pp)
    mm=0
    while mm<=50*len(pp) and sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))>1/10.0**12:
        mm+=1
        if mm%len(pp)==1:
            pass
        s=min(1,1/sum(abss(u)))
        cnt=0
        while dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(s,u)),pp),pp)>0 and s*sum(abss(u))<len(u):
            s*=2
            cnt+=1
        a=0
        b=s
        beg=a
        end=b
        A=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(a,u)),pp),pp)
        B=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(b,u)),pp),pp)
        k=0
        while k<20 and abs(A-B)>(1/10.0**12)*max(abs(A),abs(B)):
            mid=(beg+end)/2
            if dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(mid,u)),pp),pp)>0:
                beg=mid
            else:
                end=mid
            
            c=max(beg-(1/10.0**12),min(end+(1/10.0**12),b+(B/(A-B))*(b-a)))
            C=dot(u, grad(add(t,mult(c,u)),pp),pp)
            if abs(a-c)>abs(b-c) and abs(b-c)>0:
                a=b
                A=B
                b=c
                B=C
            else:
                b=a
                B=A
                a=c
                A=C
            if C>0:
                beg=max(beg,c)
            else:
                end=min(end,c)
            k+=1
                
        s=c
            
        oldgrad=grad(t,pp)
        t=add(t,mult(s,u))
        newgrad=grad(t,pp)
        uold=mult(1,u)
        u=mult(1,newgrad)
        if mm%len(pp)!=1:
            u=add(u,mult(dot(newgrad, add(newgrad,mult(-1,oldgrad)),pp)/dot(oldgrad,oldgrad,pp),uold))

    
    ss=sum(abss(grad(t,pp)))
    tt=t[:kk]
    tt.append(0)
    t=tt+t[kk:]
    if ss>1/10.0**12:
        x=str(input("Failed"))
    return t

df['New_feature'] = df.groupby('Class_ID', group_keys=False)['feature'].apply(f)
df

Did I do anything wrong? Thanks in advance.
Edit Here is a sample dataframe:
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""Class_ID  Date           Student_ID      feature  
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553                                   
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2     
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1     
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55     
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15
7         12/2/2019      3               0.1
7         12/2/2019      5               0.1
7         12/2/2019      12              0.05
7         12/2/2019      8               0.45
7         12/2/2019      6               0.3""")) 

and the desired output:
df_outcome = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""Class_ID   Date          Student_ID      feature        New_feature
1         1/1/2023       3               0.02167131     2.385963956274992
1         1/1/2023       4               0.17349148     0
1         1/1/2023       6               0.08438952     1.6510552553095719
1         1/1/2023       8               0.04143787     2.054792417419151
1         1/1/2023       9               0.02589056     2.298129663961289
1         1/1/2023       1               0.03866752     2.0916706205231286
1         1/1/2023       10              0.0461553       1.9965409929949391
3         17/4/2022      5               0.2            0.7980479577400461
3         17/4/2022      2               0.1            1.2532153405902076
3         17/4/2022      3               0.55           0
3         17/4/2022      4               0.15           0.9944188436386611
7         12/2/2019      3               0.1            1.07079092
7         12/2/2019      5               0.1            1.07079092
7         12/2/2019      12              0.05           1.46861021
7         12/2/2019      8               0.45           0
7         12/2/2019      6               0.3            0.32415155"""))


can you show what f is?

@iBeMeltin Hi, the definition of f is a bit complicated and is too long to post here. Essentially it takes an input of a list of any length n, and then output another list of length. And I would like to ask is there a way to get around the problem and to generate the new column.

I can’t answer your question because you did not provide a reproducible example of the error.

@iBelMeltin Hi, I just edited my question and included the definition of the function f, many thanks.

please refer to this when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@iBeMeltin I have updated the question and the a minimal reproducible example is now available, thank you.

@Nayrborcherds Your f function is completely unreadable. It exhibits some very bad software engineering habits. Please first refactor some of the code out of it, so that every function have no more than 25 lines (basic principle).

The method to create pp is wrong. By your code, pp is nan.
I fixed the method f below:
def f(ppp):
    kk = 0
    maxx = ppp.iloc[0]
    print(f"maxx is {maxx}")
    print(f"ppp is {ppp}")
    for k in range(len(ppp)):
        if ppp.iloc[k] > maxx:
            kk = k
            maxx = ppp.iloc[k]
    pp = pd.concat([ppp.iloc[:kk], ppp.iloc[kk + 1 :]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(f"pp is {pp}")
    t = []
    for k in range(len(pp)):
        t.append(math.sqrt(2 * math.log(1 / pp.iloc[k])))

    u = grad(t, pp)
    mm = 0
    while mm <= 50 * len(pp) and sum(abss(grad(t, pp))) > 1 / 10.0**12:
        mm += 1
        if mm % len(pp) == 1:
            pass
        s = min(1, 1 / sum(abss(u)))
        cnt = 0
        while dot(u, grad(add(t, mult(s, u)), pp), pp) > 0 and s * sum(abss(u)) < len(
            u
        ):
            s *= 2
            cnt += 1
        a = 0
        b = s
        beg = a
        end = b
        A = dot(u, grad(add(t, mult(a, u)), pp), pp)
        B = dot(u, grad(add(t, mult(b, u)), pp), pp)
        k = 0
        while k < 20 and abs(A - B) > (1 / 10.0**12) * max(abs(A), abs(B)):
            mid = (beg + end) / 2
            if dot(u, grad(add(t, mult(mid, u)), pp), pp) > 0:
                beg = mid
            else:
                end = mid

            c = max(
                beg - (1 / 10.0**12),
                min(end + (1 / 10.0**12), b + (B / (A - B)) * (b - a)),
            )
            C = dot(u, grad(add(t, mult(c, u)), pp), pp)
            if abs(a - c) > abs(b - c) and abs(b - c) > 0:
                a = b
                A = B
                b = c
                B = C
            else:
                b = a
                B = A
                a = c
                A = C
            if C > 0:
                beg = max(beg, c)
            else:
                end = min(end, c)
            k += 1

        s = c

        oldgrad = grad(t, pp)
        t = add(t, mult(s, u))
        newgrad = grad(t, pp)
        uold = mult(1, u)
        u = mult(1, newgrad)
        if mm % len(pp) != 1:
            u = add(
                u,
                mult(
                    dot(newgrad, add(newgrad, mult(-1, oldgrad)), pp)
                    / dot(oldgrad, oldgrad, pp),
                    uold,
                ),
            )

    ss = sum(abss(grad(t, pp)))
    tt = t[:kk]
    tt.append(0)
    t = tt + t[kk:]
    if ss > 1 / 10.0**12:
        x = str(input("Failed"))
    return t



Actually, this maybe a part of function, but this can run to get a result by the MRE you provided. Maybe more error was caused by the usage of pandas.

thank you so much for your help. I tried to run the code and got the following:
Class_ID Date Student_ID feature New_feature
0 1 1/1/2023 3 0.021671 NaN
1 1 1/1/2023 4 0.173491 [2.385963956274992, 0, 1.6510552553095719, 2.0...
2 1 1/1/2023 6 0.084390 NaN
3 1 1/1/2023 8 0.041438 [0.7980479577400461, 1.2532153405902076, 0, 0....
4 1 1/1/2023 9 0.025891 NaN
5 1 1/1/2023 1 0.038668 NaN
6 1 1/1/2023 10 0.046155 NaN
7 3 17/4/2022 5 0.200000 NaN
8 3 17/4/2022 2 0.100000 NaN
9 3 17/4/2022 3 0.550000 NaN
10 3 17/4/2022 4 0.150000 NaN
the list is concentrated in 1 cell for each race

Hi, it seems the error happend on the feature column,  may you give some feature data? Just fake data is ok.

Dear @lif cc , I just added some data, please see the edit for a sample data input and the desired output, many thanks.

Sorry, just discovered a mistake in the dataframe, updated just now and should now be error free.

I fixed it now, I shouldn't be using .apply and should be using .transform instead. Thank you so much for your help!

You are really good! Have fun.
